# Getting a message thread from a MySQL database based on USER and MESSAGE tables

Tags: mysql

I may be asking my SQL query to do a bit much in one hit. I'm writing a messaging script and want to display the summary list of conversation threads just like text messages work on phones; so the person the message thread is with, the date/time of the last message and the number of unread messages per user.

So consider this query, assuming the user id we're checking is 1:

```
SELECT u.id, 
       u.name, 
       u.image, 
       m.message, 
       m.sender, 
       m.sent, 
       sum(if(m.sender<>1,m.unread,0)) as unread 
FROM   messages m 
INNER JOIN members u ON u.id = m.sender OR u.id = m.receiver 
WHERE (m.sender = 1 OR m.receiver = 1) AND u.id <> 1 
GROUP BY IF(m.sender = 1, m.receiver, m.sender) 
ORDER BY m.sent DESC
```

In this the field types should be reasonably obvious. 'sender' is the id of the person who sent the message; 'receiver' the other user id; 'sent' the date/time the message was sent; and 'unread' a tinyint flag which is either 0 or 1.

For the most part this works - it gives me a list of unique conversation threads plus the correct number of unread messages, but, the message it's picking up as the last one sent always seems to be the first one, not the last one as if ORDER BY m.sent DESC is being overridden by the GROUP or JOIN. I'm obviously doing something dumb, but I just can't see it. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to solve this after much trial and error by adding another join to the messages table which simply grabbed the last unique message ID for each grouped conversation, i.e.:

```
SELECT u.id, 
       u.name, 
       u.image, 
       m.message, 
       m.sender, 
       m.sent, 
       sum(if(m.sender<>1,m.unread,0)) as unread 
FROM   messages m 
INNER JOIN members u ON u.id = m.sender OR u.id = m.receiver 
JOIN (SELECT max(id) id FROM messages GROUP BY IF(sender=1, receiver, sender)) t ON m.id = t.id
WHERE (m.sender = 1 OR m.receiver = 1) AND u.id <> 1 
GROUP BY IF(m.sender = 1, m.receiver, m.sender) 
ORDER BY m.sent DESC
```

I'm still a little confused as to why the original query wasn't picking up the last message as per the ORDER BY sent, but hey - a fix is a fix.